# Deeply nested JSON response

Tags: java, json, spring, rest

My REST API has many relationships between classes. I've encountered many problems with circular dependency within my mapping methods but I managed to resolve them. Yet still - I saw a potential problem. I am not sure if structure of my JSON responses is correct or whether it is a good idea to display such deeply nested resources. Therefore I am concerned about level of objects' nesting level. Maybe I should create separate DTOs for each endpoint so nesting level could be 'flatter'? Here is an example:

We have GET method on URL:

```
localhost:8080/api/v1/categories
```

Displayed example shows us response of relationship where we have 3 classes - `Project` class which has `@ManyToMany` relationship with `Category` class, and `@ManyToMany` and `@OneToMany` relationship with `Volunteer` class.

The response is represented as (many fields are null but JSON response is still huge):

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "categoryName": "Name Of Category",
        "categoryDescription": "Some description",
        "categoryPopularity": 50,
        "projectsCategories": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "projectName": null,
                "projectDescription": null,
                "projectDate": "1998-12-24",
                "projectVolunteers": [
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "name": "John",
                        "surname": "Doe",
                        "dateOfBirth": null,
                        "contact": null,
                        "skills": [],
                        "participatingProjects": [
                            {
                                "id": 1,
                                "projectName": null,
                                "projectDescription": null,
                                "projectDate": "1997-12-25",
                                "projectVolunteers": [
                                    1,
                                    {
                                        "id": 2,
                                        "name": "John2",
                                        "surname": "Doe",
                                        "dateOfBirth": null,
                                        "contact": null,
                                        "skills": [],
                                        "participatingProjects": [
                                            1
                                        ],
                                        "ownedProjects": [],
                                        "reputation": 5,
                                        "interests": []
                                    }
                                ],
                                "projectOwner": {
                                    "id": 1,
                                    "name": "John",
                                    "surname": "Doe",
                                    "dateOfBirth": null,
                                    "contact": null,
                                    "skills": [],
                                    "participatingProjects": [
                                        1,
                                        2
                                    ],
                                    "ownedProjects": [
                                        1
                                    ],
                                    "reputation": 5,
                                    "interests": []
                                },
                                "projectLocation": null,
                                "requiredSkills": [],
                                "projectOpinions": [
                                    {
                                        "id": 1,
                                        "opinion": "Something",
                                        "describedProject": 1,
                                        "author": 1
                                    }
                                ],
                                "projectStatus": true,
                                "tasks": [],
                                "categories": []
                            },
                            2
                        ],
                        "ownedProjects": [
                            1
                        ],
                        "reputation": 5,
                        "interests": []
                    }
                ],
                "projectOwner": null,
                "projectLocation": null,
                "requiredSkills": [],
                "projectOpinions": [],
                "projectStatus": false,
                "tasks": [],
                "categories": [
                    1
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "categoryName": "Second category",
        "categoryDescription": "Category description",
        "categoryPopularity": 50,
        "projectsCategories": []
    }
]
```

Comment: If i m not mistaken you should be able to overload the fields/attributes of your entity ie @JsonIgnore so that you can avoid displaying all the nested objects. But if you do want to display something partially, you can use Data Transfer Objects, ie for project categories create a DTO representing only ID and project name, convert the Category POJO into the DTO and use the DTO in the JSON instead.

Comment: So instead of showing a lot more extraneous details, projectCategory will only be something like `"projectsCategories": [{"id": 2, "projectName": null}, {"id": 3, "projectName": null}]`

Comment: @experimentunit1998X that's where I want to clarify the answer - I have one DTO for ```Project``` to display all projects on endpoint (for example ```localhost:8080/api/v1/projects``` ). This DTO has to give me data about participants of project and project owner. But in other parts of code, for example ```projectCategories```, we don't need that much information about ```Project```. So is it good idea to create multiple DTOs for one entity?